# how to test clicknbuy?

Tags: php, paypal

I want to test clicknbuy payment gateway like paypal sandbox? Is that possible ? If yes, how ?

Comment: You probably need to ask them whether they offer a sandbox of their own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test Paypal by using different settings for the script. Instead of using the "real" api you create a developer account. That allows you to have a fake account and fake usernames to simulate payments. When you're done with everything you can switch to using the normal api instead of the test server.

Base site: https://developer.paypal.com/

More information at https://www.x.com/community/ppx/testing
Click on "Testing Web Checkout APIs"

> Testing Web Checkout APIs PayPal Web
>   Checkout APIs includes Express
>   Checkout, Website Payments Pro, Button
>   Manager, Mass Pay, Recurring Payments,
>   and all of the Information APIs
>   Login or sign-up on
>   developer.paypal.com Create your test
>   accounts - you can learn more about
>   this in the Getting Starting Guide.
>   Get you API Credentials for your
>   Business Test Account Code and Test
>   Read the Documents Get Sample Code

Download SDKs
Use the correct endpoint
Go live :)

Comment: Nice answer, but wrong product :) He is asking about Firstgate's Click And Buy.